# Error: Cannot find module 'bonescript' in Cloud9

Tags: node.js

I got the error in Cloud9
Error: Cannot find module 'bonescript'
When the following code excuted by node.js

```
enter code here
var b = require('bonescript');
b.pinMode('USR0', b.OUTPUT);
b.pinMode('USR1', b.OUTPUT);
b.pinMode('USR2', b.OUTPUT);
b.pinMode('USR3', b.OUTPUT);
b.digitalWrite('USR0', b.HIGH);
b.digitalWrite('USR1', b.HIGH);
b.digitalWrite('USR2', b.HIGH);
b.digitalWrite('USR3', b.HIGH);
setTimeout(restore, 2000);
```

This code can be executed by command line: node blinkLed.js in the Debian Linus on BeagelBone Black without problem. It can also be run on the beaglebone.org web demo.

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

I had searched and try online solution for 6 hours, but not successful. I thought it might be Cloud9 config issue. I contact Cloud 9 support but get no solution.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Need to use the Cloud9 on the BeagleBone Black by 192.168.7.2:3000
The Cloud9 on https://ide.c9.io cannot find the correct bonescript library